# Trying to return API results but receiving type Null is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, api, http, dart

Trying to return API results but receiving type Null is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
The server status comes back with 200 so that is a good sign

```
    Future<Comps> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse('http://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions'),
    headers: {
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'api',
    },
  );

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.statusCode);

    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Comps.fromJson(
      jsonDecode(response.body),
    );
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
    throw Exception('Failed to load');
  }
}
```

Comment: Header API key was removed for security reasons and replaced with 'api'

Comment: Try printing response.body.

Comment: type Null is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' is the body when printing